# AnalyticsSettings.initializeOnStartup = false; Still send appStart event

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've tried to disable analytics in some ways, but it still sends appStart event to the dashboard.

How can I disable it properly? I need to ask user before the data is sent.  (GDPR)

And will Unity IAP work if analytics is not initialized?

I've tried in Awake and in Editor script, but not works.

```
AnalyticsSettings.initializeOnStartup = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found that I need to set
`Analytics.enabled = false; Analytics.initializeOnStartup = false;` in Awake and then 
`Analytics.enabled = true; Analytics.ResumeInitialization()` when i need to initialize it.

When I used only one of them, I got strange results.